# What is wrong with this code? I cant figure it out

Tags: python

what is wrong with this code?  Ive tried to run it but keeps giving me error and I cant figure it out.

```
def main():
    # Variables
    total_sales = 0.0

    # Initialize lists
    daily_sales = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    days_of_week = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday',
                    'Wednesday', 'Thursday' 'Friday',
                    'Saturday']

    for i in range(7):
        daily_sales[i] = float(input('Enter the sales for ' \
                                     + days_of_week[i] + ': '))

    for number in daily_sales:
        total_sales += number

    # Display total sales
    print ('Total sales for the week: $', \
           format(total_sales, ',.2f'), sep='')

# Call the main function.
main()
```

Comment: You can start figuring it out by understanding the error or understanding the flow of your code.

Comment: What is the error it gives you?

Comment: Yes, but i dont see what error i made...

Comment: it runs but then when i input a number it says there is an error in the part that says range . those 2-3 lines im assuming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
days_of_week = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday',
                'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday',
                'Saturday']
```

You forget the `,` after the 'Thursday', that's why it will out of range.

---

your code:

```
def main():
    # Variables
    total_sales = 0.0

    # Initialize lists
    daily_sales = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    days_of_week = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday',
                    'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday',
                    'Saturday']

    for i in range(7):
        daily_sales[i] = float(input('Enter the sales for ' \
                                 + days_of_week[i] + ': '))

    for number in daily_sales:
        total_sales += number

    # Display total sales
    print('Total sales for the week: ${:.2f}'.format(total_sales))

# Call the main function.
main()
```

---

And maybe we can improve this code a bit:

```
def main():
    # Initialize lists
    daily_sales = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    days_of_week = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday',
                    'Friday', 'Saturday']

    # Use `enumerate` to get the item directly.
    for index, day in enumerate(days_of_week):
        daily_sales[index] = float(
            input('Enter the sales for {0}: '.format(day)))

    # Use the built-in `sum` to sum the sales.
    total_sales = sum(daily_sales)

    # Display total sales
    print('Total sales for the week: ${:.2f}'.format(total_sales))


# Call the main function.
main()
```

Comment: I think the error is on the display total sales. Could please try this one: `print('Total sales for the week: ${:.2f}'.format(total_sales))`

Comment: That didint fix it, i think its the part that     says for i in range(7):
    daily_sales[i] = float(input('Enter the sales for ' \
                                 + days_of_week[i] + ': '))

Comment: Without the error log, I can't figure out the problem. See my edit and have a try.

Comment: My pleasure. I've also updated the answer and provide a better answer :) By the way, next time you may provide us a detailed error log so we can help you much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I found some indentation error when throwing it into my editor.  After fixing it, and adding the `,` after `'Thursday'` that @lord63. j found, you need to clean up and fix your final `print` statement in `main()`.  Try the below code, as it is working well for me, now:

```
def main():
 # Variables
    total_sales = 0.0

 # Initialize lists
    daily_sales = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    days_of_week = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday',
                'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday',
                'Saturday']

    for i in range(7):
        daily_sales[i] = float(input('Enter the sales for '+ \
                                      days_of_week[i] + ': '))

    for number in daily_sales:
        total_sales += number

    # Display total sales
    print ('Total sales for the week: $' \
           + format(total_sales, '.2f'))

# Call the main function.
main()
```

Comment: I try that and it says " unexpected character after line continuation character"

Comment: Ah.  I must have added an extra blank space after the slash.  Deleting the white-space makes it work and I've updated the answer.